# How to pass data to an array of Doubles in a Class

Tags: ios, swift4

Here's the code. I use it just fine in other cases but with an array, I keep getting nil. The data is parsed just fine and I can print it into the console from the closure. However, when I try to pass it into my View Controller, it's not getting there.

```
class AllPointRU {

//    var allPointsDict: [String:AnyObject] = [:]
    var _lngs: [Double]!
    var _lats: [Double]!

    var lngs: [Double] {
        if _lngs == nil {
            _lngs = [1.1]
        }
        return _lngs
    }

    var lats: [Double] {
        if _lats == nil {
            _lats = [1.1]
        }
        return _lats
    }
func downloadAllPointsRU(completed: DownloadComplete) {

    Alamofire.request(CURRENT_POINTS_RU).responseJSON { response in

        if response.data != nil {
            let allPointsRU = response.result.value!
            if let allLat = allPointsRU as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                let latitudes = allLat.map({ $0["lat"] as! Double})
                self._lats = latitudes

            }
            if let allLng = allPointsRU as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                let longitudes = allLng.map({ $0["lng"] as! Double})
                self._lngs = longitudes


            }
        }
    }
    completed()
}

}
```

Comment: Please share the data what you are getting from API service, @Anton Platonov

Comment: Probably unrelated but private backing variables with leading underscores in Swift are horrible. This is not Objective-C. Declare `lngs` and `lats` as `private var lngs = [Double]()` or if you really need the lazy instantiation `lazy private var lngs = [1.1]`. The `private` keyword prevents the variable from being mutated outside of the class. And a JSON dictionary in Swift 3+ is always `[String:Any]`, not `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a async api call, you either need to wait for the response that is going to passed to the other view controller or you can user closure to capture the value and then pass those value to the other view controller.

> You probably are passing value to the other view controller before you get api response that may be the reason you are getting nil.

Comment: The thing is the same code works just fine with other classes without arrays. There must be something wrong with this code.